# Can I finish a marathon without finishing training?

Tags: running, long-distance-running, running-training-plan, marathon

I'm new to running (casually started last year, running on & off). I've since run a few 5ks & 10ks. My weekly mileage is ~20 miles/week with longest run of 15 miles.

If it makes any difference, I've done all of my training w/out taking anything with me (gu, water, gatorade). I just completed a half-marathon in two hours flat with negative splits and didn't feel much leg pain until the last couple of miles.

My first full marathon is in three weeks. I completely mismarked it on my calendar (weeks earlier than I had initially thought) and also missed a couple weeks of critical training (prior to the half marathon).

I realize I won't be able to run the entire thing but really hope to at least *finish* by adopting some sort of strategy like alternating running/walking and not be miserable.

Can I expect to finish the marathon?

What should be my walk:run ratio and/or pace to safely finish based on the half?

What sort of training if any can  I do the three weeks prior?

EDIT: I've read this [post](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/15011/should-i-run-a-marathon-without-training-for-it-if-im-training-for-half-maratho?rq=1). I'm asking more about *how* or *if* I can finish rather than whether or not I *should* *try*.

**UPDATE**: I finished the marathon (on five hours sleep with a long run of 18 miles). I ran most of it. The first 15 were a breeze. Had some ups & downs for the following 6 miles. The last 5 miles were a bit rough but at that point there was no turning back (and I was so happy with the running community's encouragement when we crossed paths!). Felt good to cross the finish line in a reasonable amount of time. It was definitely mind over matter at that point though, I look forward to running another one with proper training and beating my time!

Comment: Does your definition of finish allow for walking? If so, you'd almost certainly finish unless you were injured during the marathon itself. At this point of your training, it's more a matter of willpower that will determine whether or not you finish. Now whether you get a great time is a different story...

Comment: @JW8 yes, I think it _has_ to allow for walking at this point.

Comment: Congrats on the completion! Well played.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, I think that if you can run a 1/2 marathon, you should be able to at least complete a marathon.

The method that I am going to suggest is called the Galloway Run/Walk program. There is a [good PDF article here](http://jeffgalloway.com/pdf/walkbreaks.pdf), that has a chart for pacing and how much to run or walk by pace.

Make sure to read/note this paragraph:

> Runners: Remember that long ones should be at least 2 min/mi slower than your projected finish pace in the half or full marathon. An additional slowdown should be made for increased temperature: 30 sec per mile slower for each 5 degrees of temperature increase above 60˚ F. It is always safer to take more frequent breaks.

So using the [Cool Running pace calculator](http://www.coolrunning.com/engine/4/4_1/96.shtml) (Love this tool), you are slightly over 9 minutes/mile for a 2 hour half marathon. I would then go to 11 minutes per mile for the marathon, which would be 2:30 minutes running, 1:00 minute walking. In theory, that *should* allow you to complete the marathon.

For the training prior, I would just continue your 20 mile weeks, since there isn't really that much to taper. I would back off on the intensity a bit for any speedwork you are doing, and get a couple of good days rest leading up to the event.